# Why in PowerShell: for ($i=0; -le $total-1; $i++) instead of for ($i=0; -lt $total; $i++)

Tags: powershell

I'm looking at some code examples on powershellpro.com and don't understand why he wrote sample code that loops through an array by:

...having an increment start at zero then increase by one until it is less than or equal to the length of an array minus one...

```
for ($i=0; $i -le $total-1; $i++)
```

...instead of having the increment start at zero then increase by one until it is less than the length of the array...

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $total; $i++)
```

Am I missing something? They are functionally equivalent and will both loop through each item in the array. Personally I think the second version is cleaner. Is there a best practice or something that says you should use the first one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

>> Am I missing something? 
**No**

>> Is there a best practice or something that says you should use the first one? 
usage of 'for' cycle in powershell is the same like in any other language. just depends on attitude of the programmer which style he uses.

Comment: I would only say that shorter, simpler code is often easier to read and understand.

Comment: Could be a habit from tight-loop optimizations in another language because of iterator behavior. In a lot of cases, decrementing your indices would be faster, often because of the underlying data structure. Though, usually, you would be subtracting, not adding, so maybe this was a case of anti-pattern (or misunderstood application and then mis-use)..

Answer (score 4):

Both are functionally equivalent, but the more concise the code, the easier it is to read for some people.  Also, I think there's a syntax problem with the original poster's question.  (Correct me if I'm wrong.)  I mention this not as a critique, but only for in the event that a novice reads this and is confused.  Many may consider this the best version of the code snippet in question:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $total; $i++){
  #do something
}
```

Note the $i in the condition segment before -lt.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no difference. it's just matter of taste. The first fragment will stop the loop **when is**  `$i=$total-1`. The second **before** `$i=$total`. it's exactly the same.

IMHO